# Where are the arguments critter & vector defined in Eloquent JavaScript Chapter 7

Tags: javascript

Working slowly through the Eloquent JavaScript book by Marijn Haverbeke and am trying to get my head around the first step of the World.turn() function:

```
World.prototype.turn = function() {
  var acted = [];
  this.grid.forEach(function(critter, vector) {

    if (critter.act && acted.indexOf(critter) == -1) {
      acted.push(critter);
      this.letAct(critter, vector);
    }
  }, this);
};
```

Where does the prototype forEach function get the arguments critter and vector from.

When I log their output to the console, I get an object with the originChar and a direction if valid, but can't get my head around where it is getting the arguments.

The link to the section is as follows: http://eloquentjavascript.net/07_elife.html#h_6OGIzAd5Tr

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `World` owns a `Grid`, which has `forEach` defined on it [just above](http://eloquentjavascript.net/07_elife.html#p_/IbAQkWKaF) the section you're looking at.

```
Grid.prototype.forEach = function(f, context) {
  for (var y = 0; y < this.height; y++) {
    for (var x = 0; x < this.width; x++) {
      var value = this.space[x + y * this.width];
      if (value != null)
        f.call(context, value, new Vector(x, y));
    }
  }
};
```

The grid's cells contain critters, which you see captured in `var value = this.space[x + y * this.width]` and passed to the function you provide `forEach`, along with `new Vector(x, y)` containing the location in the grid.

Comment: Apologies, I am still not clear on what the Grid.prototype.forEach is doing. What is f, and what is context?

Comment: See that the `turn` function passes `function(critter, vector) {...}` and `this` to `forEach`, which it names `f` and `context`. They are the function you want to run on each item and the context (scope) to run the function in. That way when your function is executed by `f.call(context, ...)`, the variables, etc. you expect are present. Read [This and its Scope](http://eloquentjavascript.net/07_elife.html#h_EoVtgPzygv) more carefully.

Comment: Thanks Kristján, will ready it more carefully now. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: Ok, I think I understand this a lot better now! 
There are 2 args passed to the `Grid.prototype.forEach` - the `this` reference to the world object, the `critter` and the `vector`.

The `this` in the `turn` method is the arg `context` and the `f` arg is the function with the `critter` and `vector` args.

The only bit I am still unsure of is where the arguments `(critter, vector)` from the `turn` method are coming from?

Apologies if you have explained this already, I get the sense I am being a bit stupid :)

Comment: The `critter` is pulled from the grid and passed as `value` in `f.call(context, value, new Vector(x, y))`. The `vector` is also there as the third argument.

Comment: So the Grid.prototype.forEach is getting the data for those arguments by looping over the grid, and setting the value with the call to the  `this.space` array and calling `new` on the `Vector` function with the co-ords from the index of the two loops.

Comment: Yes. Terminology-wise, the call to `new Vector()` is executing `Vector`'s [constructor](http://eloquentjavascript.net/06_object.html#h_YKXJZqcaJA).